# Return last 5 results based on date and group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried my best to google this over the past few days but I cannot find the solution that I need for MS Access or MySQL

I have a table of soccer results where I want to pull back the last 5 results per home team based on the date.

I have tried this in access following MS advice and I cannot get it to work how it says it should.  I am quite new to MySQL and got a bit closer with the below code but that only returns the last result and if I change it to 2 it will not run due to Subquery returns more than 1 row.  I don't need the exact answer I am happy if someone can give me a link to follow for either Access or MySQL.  Below is what I was using which did return the last result fine.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TBL_ALL_English_Results t1
WHERE t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
             FROM TBL_ALL_English_Results t2
             WHERE t2.Home_Team = t1.Home_Team            
             ORDER BY t2.id DESC
             LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a correlated count aggregate query that calculates a rank order of records by `DATE` and `HOME_TEAM` group, then uses this rank order to filter query results. Below should be compliant in MySQL and MS Access, even SQL Server and other dialects.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TBL_ALL_English_Results t1 
INNER JOIN 
 (
   SELECT t2.Home_Team, t2.Date, 
          (SELECT Count(*) FROM TBL_ALL_English_Results sub
            WHERE t2.Date <= sub.Date 
            AND t2.Home_Team = sub.Home_Team) AS GameOrder 
   FROM TBL_ALL_English_Results As t2
  )  AS LastFiveDates 
ON t1.Date = LastFiveDates.Date
AND t1.Home_Team = LastFiveDates.Home_Team
WHERE LastFiveDates.GameOrder <= 5
```

While most databases can run this query, performance may differ especially in the file level database, MS Access, if table results are above 10,000 as opposed to the server level RDMS, MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL makes this a bit difficult.  Probably the easiest way is to use variables:

```
SELECT aer.*
FROM (SELECT aer.*,
             (@rn := if(@ht = aer.Home_Team, @rn + 1,
                        if(@ht := aer.Home_Team, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM TBL_ALL_English_Results aer CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @ht := '', @rn := 0) params
      ORDER BY aer.Home_Team, aer.id DESC
     ) aer
WHERE rn <= 5;
```

Comment: wow I am totally lost with what is going on in the above as I said I am new to MySQL.  However I thank you for your time but I am receiving the below error as I am lost with this I do not know where to look  **'  [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@ht := aer.Home_Team, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
   ' at line 4 '**

Comment: This is using variables to enumerate the rows in the table for each home team.  This is often the simplest approach in MySQL.  In most other databases (but not MS Access), you would use the ANSI standard function `row_number()`.